# Array not in Order

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to generate a card deck for a game. 
How come my array is not in order when I print it out? 
Expected Output:

```
 [
        {number: 1, suite: "Hearts", points: 1},
        {number: 2, suite: "Hearts", points: 2},
        ...
    ]
```

The result I get when I print it out is:

```
[
    {number: 2, suite: "Hearts", points: 2},
    {number: 4, suite: "Hearts", points: 4},
    {number: 13, suite: "Clubs", points: 10},
    {number: 5, suite: "Diamonds", points: 5},
    {number: 4, suite: "Spades", points: 4},
    {number: 13, suite: "Diamonds", points: 10},
    ...
]
```

I'm not sure why this is... How can I fix the order?

Are arrays of objects generally not in order?

```js
function generateCards() {
  deck = []
  let i = 1;
  let j = 1;
  for (j = 1; j < 5; j++) {
    let suite = ""
    switch (j) {
      case (1):
        suite = "Hearts"
        break;
      case (2):
        suite = "Diamonds"
        break;
      case (3):
        suite = "Clubs"
        break;
      case (4):
        suite = "Spades"
        break;
    }
    for (i = 1; i < 14; i++) {
      switch (i) {
        case (11):
          points = 10;
          break;
        case (12):
          points = 10;
          break;
        case (13):
          points = 10;
          break;
        default:
          points = i;
          break;
      }
      card = {
        "number": i,
        "suite": suite,
        "points": points
      }
      deck.push(card)
    }
  }
  console.log(deck)
  return deck;
}


generateCards();
```

Comment: Which part isn't in order?

Comment: what means order in this case?

Comment: @Ryan edited my question!!

Comment: @NinaScholz edited my question!

Comment: your array is in the order of creation.

Comment: I don't understand. I created it with a loop, how come it's in a random order?

Comment: there is no random element, beside some use of undeclared variables.

Comment: I don't get it, I'm sorry. What's the pattern to my output?

Comment: How can I fix it?

Comment: Running that code as shown **does** produce expected order you mention at top. https://jsfiddle.net/6rwzsywv/ If the order has changed it is not from the code shown

Comment: Do you sort the array somewhere in your code after you create it? Sort is mutating the array, and `console.log()` might show you the array after sorting.

Answer (score 1):

This won't fix the order problem (which I can't reproduce), but will shorten your code considerably.

```js
function generateCards() {
  const suites = ['Hearts', 'Diamonds', 'Clubs', 'Spades'];
  const deck = []

  for (let j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
    for (let i = 1; i < 14; i++) {
      deck.push({
        number: i,
        suite: suites[j],
        points: i >= 11 ? 10 : i
      });
    }
  }

  return deck;
}


console.log(generateCards());
```

And you can even compact it to a single loop:

```js
function generateCards() {
  const suites = ['Hearts', 'Diamonds', 'Clubs', 'Spades'];
  const deck = []

  for (let i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
    const number = i % 13 + 1;
    
    deck.push({
      number,
      suite: suites[i / 13 | 0], // divide by 13 and round down
      points: number >= 11 ? 10 : number
    });
  }

  return deck;
}


console.log(generateCards());
```

Comment: I like this code much better. And it generates the array in the correct order.